# Latest nuget packge for FluentAssertions missing System.Xml references

Tags: fluent-assertions

FluentAssertions nuget package for 1.7 seems to be missing the references for System.Xml and System.Xml.Linq

Is anyone else experiencing this problem?

Comment: You're right. We fixed this in the trunk on CodePlex, so it will be definitely part of 1.8.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know Dennis

Comment: Please mark the question as answered. Otherwise it keeps appearing in the unanswered section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get the latest NuGet package (1.7.1.1), you'll find that your problem is fixed now.